# How to form a face loop around a bend?

Tags: edges

I am trying to understand how topology works.
As shown in the image with the blue line, I want to be able to insert new edge loops (i.e. similar to the yellow line) around a 90 degree bend. What's the best way to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setup will help you to do that loop.
[image]

Comment: be careful with quads that have 3 vertices on a single line - if triangulated improperly, one triangle will have 0 area...